# Selenium Out of focus element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a scenario in selenium where I have a web element which is available on the page but to reach out to that web element sometimes we have to scroll down depending upon some business logic. 
I don't want to use javascript executor and css selector. Is there any other way we can check if element is not clickable I can try to see if there is a scroll down scroller available? And my driver should scroll down and try to check that element once before it actually throw exception.

Comment: What language are using? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Java and I have tried using javascript executor.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your Questions one by one.

1. `we have to scroll down` : When you think of scroll its worth mentioning that scroll method is not a method of Webdriver, this is a method of JavaScript. JavascriptExecutor is an Interface which is available in  package `org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor`. Inside this Interface we have a method called `executeScript()` – so whatever script you will pass as a string it will be executed by JavascriptExecutor.
2. `I don't want to use javascript executor` : We are not using anything separate stuff by the name JavascriptExecutor. We are using the same instance of WebDriver i.e. driver,  but we need to downcast it so that it can act as a JavascriptExecutor to perform whatever script you will pass as a string.
3. `css selector` : Using `css selector` is not mandatory. Selenium provides you the flexibility to use any of the properties of a particular element available like id/name/linkText/xpath.

Let me know if this answers your Question.

Comment: I agree what u said above but I need another way to check the page and scroll. As I have mentioned in my question very clearly I don't want to do it through JavascriptExecutor. Is there any other way I can do it ?